# why free function inside namespace is ambiguous?

Tags: c++, gcc

--myfunc.hh

```
#ifndef MY_FUNC_HH
#define MY_FUNC_HH

namespace abc
{
int xyz (int a, int b);
}

#endif
```

--myfunc.cc

```
#include "myfunc.hh"

using namespace abc;

int xyz (int a, int b)
{
    if (!b)
        return 0;
    return xyz (b, b/a);
}
```

$ `g++ -c -g myfunc.cc myfunc.hh`

```
myfunc.cc: In function ‘int xyz(int, int)’:
myfunc.cc:9: error: call of overloaded ‘xyz(int&, int)’ is ambiguous
myfunc.cc:5: note: candidates are: int xyz(int, int)
myfunc.hh:6: note:                 int abc::xyz(int, int)
```

Why is `xyz` overloaded when there's only one function named xyz defined here?

isn't the `using namespace abc` telling the compiler to look for name xyz in namespace abc?
For example, when you use the std::copy function

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void afunction()
{
   copy(blah, blah, blah);
}
```

all works fine, why should abc::xyz be any different here? Or, is it because the recursive call? if so, why?

Comment: You can't reopen a namespace with a `using namesapce` directive.  You have to specifically put your `xyz` implementation within the `abc` namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think in myfunc.cc you want to write

```
#include "myfunc.hh"

namespace abc {

int xyz (int a, int b)
{
    if (!b)
        return 0;
    return xyz (b, b/a);
}

}
```

This way you **define** the `abc::xyz` function you declared in the `.h` file. The way you wrote it you define an `xyz` function outside the namespace `abc` while also importing the one which was declared in the namespace. Thus the ambiguity.

Agreeing with @cHao and @JonathanWakely suggestion, I favor this better syntax:

```
int abc::xyz (int a, int b)
{
    if (!b)
        return 0;
    return xyz (b, b/a);
}
```

Indeed it ensure that `abc::xyz` has been correctly declared in the header file.

Comment: For reference, you can say `int abc::xyz(int a, int b) { /* ... */ }` as well.

Comment: Some people (including me) think it's _better_ to define it as `int abc::xyz(int a, int b) { ... }` as @cHao suggests, because if the signature doesn't match an earlier declaration then you get a compiler error, instead of accidentally adding a new overload.

Answer (score 1):

In your `myfunc.cc` file you overload the function xyz. That means you are defining a completely new function. There is one that is <strike>local</strike> in global namespace, there is one in the namespace `abc`.

The statement `using namespace abc;` in your example, introduces the ambiguity actually, rather than solving it. Your call is ambiguous in the sense that compiler have no idea which function to call.

Comment: `s/local/in the global namespace/`.  The defined `abc` isn't "local" unless it's declared in an anonymous namespace or declared as `static`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between these two codes:

-- myfunc.cc

```
#include "myfunc.hh"

using namespace abc;

int xyz (int a, int b)
{
    if (!b)
        return 0;
    return xyz (b, b/a);
}
```

-- myfunc.cc

```
#include "myfunc.hh"

namespace abc {

int xyz (int a, int b)
{
    if (!b)
        return 0;
    return xyz (b, b/a);
}

}
```

The first makes use of `abc` namespace, but `xyz` is defined at the "top" namespace; there are 2 functions defined. The second gives the implementation of the `abc::xyz` function.

In your case you want to do the second.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be asking why there are two versions of `xyz(int, int)` visible when you explicitly went and told the compiler to make `xyz(int, int)` visible and then defined another one?

What, exactly, do you expect the compiler to do here? It isn't going to guess for you so it gives you an error.

If you need to call one or the other, use the scope operator and an explicit namespace. You could call `::xyz(1, 2)` or `abc::xyz(1, 2)` for example.